# Laravel Array to View

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**My collection looks like this**

```
array:3 [▼
  "label" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "onhold"
    1 => "approved"
  ]
  "data" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
  ]
  "chart_data" => "{"label":["onhold","approved"],"data":[1,1]}"
]
```

I would like to pass chart_data to my blade VIEW. It should show something like this

Onhold    1
Approved  1

I tried the following to no luck

```
  @foreach ($data as $datum)
  {{$datum['label']}}
  {{$datum['data']}}
  @endforeach
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: do foreach to this array not solve your problem , you should refactoring your array to be like this 
$data['chart_data'] = [ onhold=>1 , 'approved' => 1  ] , key ( your label )  value  ( your data ) you can print it direct , in your view or foreach if $data contain alote of items inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@for` in your blade

```
@for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {{$datum['label'][$i]}}
    {{$datum['data'][$i]}}
@endfor
```

Comment: you can also use `@foreach($data as $i => $datum)` then use that $i similarly

Comment: @bhucho Yep. There are a lot of approaches for achieving this.